# How do i code so that my button after clicking will direct user to the footer in the same html?

Tags: javascript, html

How do i code so that my button onclick will link to my footer section class named "footeradc" in the same html

Comment: What do you mean by “link to”? What precisely do you want to achieve? Where’s your code and what have you tried?

Comment: There are probably hundreds of duplicates of this in SO, plus this question would get solved by reading any HTML links tutorial or reference, or probably even by googling the very title of the question.

Comment: <button onclick="contactFunction()" id="mytotopBtn" title="Get In Touch">Get In Touch</button>
  
  <script>
   function contactFunction(){
    document.body.scrollContact = 100;
    document.documentElement.scrollContact = 100;
   }
  </script>

Comment: sorry new to stackoverflow they do not allow me to post what i have on so  i just post a question instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `id` to your footer.

```
<div id='myFooter' ...>
```

Make the user click on a `<a>` like below,

```
<a href='#myFooter'/>
```

---

[Click here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682967/how-do-i-code-so-that-my-button-after-clicking-will-direct-user-to-the-footer-in/51683008#footer)

Comment: Thanks i understand how to do already

Comment: @CrystalLancer You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the id selector:

```html
<a href="#footer">Visit my footer</a>
```